# get deferred promise value jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, es6-promise, jquery-deferred

I have below function

```
function commentCount(id) {
    var deferred = new $.Deferred()
    var url =
      _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl +
      "/_api/lists/getByTitle('Comments')/items?$select=Id&$filter=ItemID eq " +
      id +
      " and Title eq 'Colleague'"
    getData(url).then(function(data) {
      deferred.resolve(data.d.results.length)
    })
    return deferred.promise()
  }
```

Now I want to return that value in HTML string as below but it shows [object object]

```
'<div class="card-footer"> <div class="row "><div class="col-lg mobile-center"><a href="#">' + commentCount(item.Id)
```

How can I get value like that

Comment: It is integer value

Comment: `commentCount` is going to return a promise,.. Using deferred doesn't change things here, you could have just done  `return getData(url).`

Comment: Can you please show me example

Comment: Unless you say used `async / await` your can't do something like `"some string" + somePromise()`,  you need to resolve your promise first.  If using `async / await`, this could be done -> `"some string" + await somePromise()`

Comment: How we can do that

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is returning a promise and you  have to resolve that promise before you can get at the data

It is also using a needless `$.Deferred` since `getData()` returns a promise

Needs to be something like:

```
function commentCount(id) {

  var url ='....';

   // return the getData promise 
  return getData(url).then(function(data) {
    // return the count to next `then()` in chain
    return data.d.results.length
  })

}

commentCount(someId).then(function(count){
   // do stuff with your html here
    var str ='<div> Count:' + count + '</div>';
})
```